# Реализация "Хлебных крошек"

Tags: php, mysql

Есть такая структура бд:

[image]

Как можно реализовать хлебные крошки?

Comment: еще немного покурить и не только хлебные крошки но и стакан нарулите, *как структура единственной таблицы бд относится к [этому](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0) ?*

Answer (score 5):

не понимаю толком вашего вопроса

если всё же понимаю, то вам надо в шаблоне сделать, что-то вроде (написано на псевдокоде, подозрительно похожем на джанго):

```
{{ objects.get(id=(objects.get(id=id).id_parent)).title }} > {{ objects.get(id=id).title }}
```

в случае, если уровней больше двух, то можно генерировать рекурсивно с конца